# how to install reactjs on windows 8

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am following steps to install reactjs from his official website https://facebook.github.io/react/

just look at error I'm getting.

> C:\Windows\System32>npm install create-react-app -g npm ERR!
>   Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-react-app" "-g"
>   npm ERR! node v7.9.0 npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null npm ERR! npm ERR! If you
>   need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\NULLPLEX5-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-05-26T12
>   _03_16_585Z-debug.log
>
> C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: So, did you search that error? Because there's multiple hits on SO already for your error, and some of those have answers. Did you read them? They you try what they suggested? Did none of the work?

Comment: Yes I have searched for this error and got some solution but these are not working to me. Some buddy told me to do like this 

git clone https://github.com/hughsk/npm-quickfix.git
cd npm-quickfix
npm set registry http://localhost:8080/

But its not work on my side.

Comment: Don't put "I was told to try X, Y, Z but  that didn't work" in the comment thread. Please update your post with that information, as well as links to questions on SO that you already tried, explaining what the result of that was for you, so that people know what you've tried. Also please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which has important information on what you've been expected to have already done before you posted, and explains how to structure your question so that it's worth answering for people.